# Grey out certain columns from my table based on certain conditions

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsp

I have a .jsp page that displays a payment table with 4 columns. Based on the type of user signed in, I want to grey out the non-available options. If someone is a full subscriber will have only pay as you go available to them and grey out the rest as an example. If is on a basic, will 1, 3, 4 column will be available and 2 grey out. I know I can identify what options should be displayed by checking the length of ${subs.costs}"

Can I do this with just jquery, css and what is the code for it based on the parameter above?

My html is:

```
        <!-- TBODY -->
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <th> pay as you go</th>
            <th> Basic subscription</th>
            <th> Advanced subscription</th>
            <th> Full Subscription</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>price</td>
            <td>price</td>
            <td>price</td>
            <td>price</td>
         </tr>           
  </tbody> 
  </table>
```

Comment: What values do you expect to have available, with what variable name, to indicate the type of user? What options are (un)available to each type of user? What have you tried in order to achieve this?

Comment: I have: ${subs.type=="Credits"} for one column, "${subs.premium}"> for the full subscription,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to know attributes of the subscriber that may not be available in the view, you are probably better setting the css on the server rather than with jquery ...